# fatal: command line, '\/\/( ){0,}beforeEach\(async\(\(\) => \{$': Unmatched \{

Tags: regex, git, typescript, git-grep

I am looking for the list of files where some tests are commented like

```
//     beforeEach(async(() => {
//   beforeEach(async(() => {
 //     beforeEach(async(() => {
//    beforeEach(async(() => {
```

From https://regex101.com/

```
\/\/( ){0,}beforeEach\(async\(\(\) => \{$
```

works fine, ... but inside the terminal I got

```
git grep "\/\/( ){0,}beforeEach\(async\(\(\) => \{$"
fatal: command line, '\/\/( ){0,}beforeEach\(async\(\(\) => \{$': Unmatched \{
```

Comment: If you need a POSIX BRE compliant regex, you need to know how to "convert" regex101 regexps to those. Try `git grep "// *beforeEach(async(() => {$"`

Comment: Thank you!!! it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the pattern complies with the POSIX BRE standard.

Use

```
git grep "// *beforeEach(async(() => {$"
```

That is, `(` in a POSIX BRE expression matches a literal `(` and `{` matches a literal `{`.

When you escape the open brace, `\{`, it starts a *range quantifier*, and thus `\}` is expected and hence is the error, `Unmatched \{`.